# Why does the producer consumer code below not need a volatile variable?

Tags: java, concurrency, producer-consumer

The way I see it, the producer and consumer threads can both cache count separately and make bad decisions as a result. If the variable is not volatile, count++ may just update the caches right?

```
class Buffer {
        private char [] buffer;
        private int count = 0, in = 0, out = 0;

        Buffer(int size)
        {
             buffer = new char[size];
        }

        public synchronized void Put(char c) {
             while(count == buffer.length) 
             {
                  try { wait(); }
                  catch (InterruptedException e) { } 
                  finally { } 
             } 
             System.out.println("Producing " + c + " ...");
             buffer[in] = c; 
             in = (in + 1) % buffer.length; 
             count++; 
             notify(); 
        }

        public synchronized char Get() {
             while (count == 0) 
             {
                  try { wait(); }
                  catch (InterruptedException e) { } 
                  finally { } 
             } 
             char c = buffer[out]; 
             out = (out + 1) % buffer.length;
             count--;
             System.out.println("Consuming " + c + " ..."); 
             notify(); 
             return c;
        }
  }
```

Comment: Follow the Java Naming Conventions: method names should start with lowercase. And that empty `finally` block is not necessary.

Comment: Tell Villanova http://www.csc.villanova.edu/~mdamian/threads/javamonitors.html

Comment: That's just terrible. How do we tell them? @MCEmperor

Comment: Normally I would leave this without taking action, but this is about an article of someone with a master degree in Computer Science. And that's just rude. Therefore I'm already sending an email ;-)

Answer (score 5):

No, both methods are defined with the `synchronized` keyword this means that they will never be executed at the same time and also that the **memory will be synchronized**. `volatile` is never needed for variables that are accessed inside a `synchronized` block.

If we would use other synchronization mechanisms provided by Java, for example `ReentrantReadWriteLock` instead of `synchronized` we also would not need `volatile`, because properly used locks have the same memory guarantees(happen-before relationship using the official language).

> ### [Memory Consistency Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility)
>
> Actions prior to "releasing" synchronizer methods such as Lock.unlock, Semaphore.release, and CountDownLatch.countDown happen-before actions subsequent to a successful "acquiring" method such as Lock.lock, Semaphore.acquire, Condition.await, and CountDownLatch.await on the same synchronizer object in another thread.

Comment: Yep. *"This guarantees that changes to the state of the object are visible to all threads."* See [Synchronized Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html).

Comment: If we used locks instead of synchronized statements, would volatile be necessary?

Comment: @Vikas, If we use locks we also don't need the volatile, as properly used locks are guaranting a happens before relation.

Comment: Synchronized actually uses locks: every object comes with a lock - the synchronized keyword uses this lock.

Comment: @Gewure That's correct, and the section about locks, wasn't added by me. I think vikas was asking about other locks like `ReentrantReadWriteLock` for example. They are not implemented with the `synchronized` keyword but they also have the same memory guarantees. I will update the answer to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

As Oleg said. The synchronized keyword both mean that the block won't be executed in parallel and that the memory will be synchronized i.e. written to main memory.

This means that adding synchronized or volotile to the count variable in the above code won't do anything, since the count variable is only accessed in synchronized sections.

Answer (score 0):

According to :-

[Synchronized Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html)

> when a synchronized method exits, it automatically establishes
>   a happens-before relationship with any subsequent invocation of a
>   synchronized method for the same object. This guarantees that changes
>   to the state of the object are visible to all threads.

So all the caches are flushed and changes synchronized with main memory once a thread gives-up a lock. So in the code above we don't need a volatile keyword for instance variables.